# When would I need TransactionScopeOption.Supress?

Tags: .net, transactionscope

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption.aspx) defines this option as

> The ambient transaction context is suppressed when creating the scope.
>   All operations within the scope are done without an ambient
>   transaction context.

When would I ever need this?

Answer (score 0):

This useful in times you have multiple transactions in the server. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851530/1080742) a good explanation and about the [`.Supress`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2008/01/11/suppressing-transactions-during-an-operation.aspx).