# Transactions in MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, transactions, commit, rollback

Was wondering if there are any transactions support in asp.net for MVC 2? i.e. commit & rollback?

I have a few slightly risky db transacts which i'd prefer firmed up with transactions.

could the [system transactions namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.aspx) be incorporated into a respository of db calls?

Answer (score 1):

Transaction support is the same in MVC as it is in WebForms. Your transaction code will be done on the back-end so the fact thats it's MVC is irrelevant.
...unless I didnt understand your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks, was having a problem finding any sample code that allows me to run a rollback, so needed some reassurance that there was transaction support.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net appears to be the sort of answers I wanted here