# Delete Database, if creating goes wrong

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I created a `C#` application, this application creates a database on first launch, this `database` which is an `SQLiteDatabase` will be stored in the project folder. The process of filling this `database` takes on a mid-range notebook around 5 to 10 seconds. So it will be slower on low-budget notebooks. There isn't a big chance, but what if somebody force closes the application, while the `database` is being created? Or what if a power failure occurs? The result of this will come out in a broken `database`, which will never work.

I'am creating my `Database` in `c#` and also fill it from `c#`, this happens within a `try` and `catch`, should I `delete` the `Database` whenever the code within the `catch` is called? My applications checks at the beginning of the application whether there already is a `database` yes or no? if there isn't it will be created.

What should I do? `Delete` the `database` when an error occurs(code goes trough `catch`) or does somebody has a better solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Some answers has been given to me:

I saw the following code, how can I use this code? Should I put the code that creates my database within the CallAMethodThatDoesSomeWork method?

```
using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope()) {
    CallAMethodThatDoesSomeWork();
    CallAMethodThatDoesSomeMoreWork();
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use begin and commit transaction? if any error occurs, rollback transaction.

Comment: Yes, put all your code inside the TransactionScope, and leave tran.Complete() at the end.

Comment: Is, it really that easy? Thanks for your help:) One more little question, I'am still running my code between the try braces, can I delete them now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *transactions* and creating all commands that uses database under it.
If application crashes, nothing will be created.
This is a standard approach.
See, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net)

Comment: What reference do I need to TransactionScope?

Comment: You need to use System.Transactions

Comment: hmmm, I should add a reference then, because just typing: System.Transactions doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite seems to support [transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html). So, open a transaction, then populate the data, and only `COMMIT` when it's all done.

Whenever your application starts, you can surely check whether there's *no* data in the database (in which case, something went wrong the last time you tried to populate it).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use begin and commit transaction? if any error occurs, rollback transaction.

For more on transactions refer link below.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html