# How to implement Transaction?

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on sql, my query is that i have some methods in which i am doing different-different tasks. for example:-
1st method - Inserting
2nd method - Updation
3rd method - deletion
4th methos - Inserting

now i want to execute all these in once. but if somehow any error occur then the whole process roll back it self.

code :

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to submit the information? Click 'Yes' to Submit or 'No' to re-Check.", "eParty - Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        INSERT();
        UPDATE();
        DELETE();
        INSERTAGAIN();

        MessageBox.Show("Booked successfully.", "eParty - Done!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

now how to implement Transaction at 'btnSubmit_Click' method...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
  {
    INSERT();
    UPDATE();
    DELETE();
    INSERTAGAIN();

    scope.Complete(); //if we make it here - commit the changes, 
                      //if not - everything is rolled back

  }
```

remember to include `System.Transactions` to you project

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what db access technology you have.

If you use Entity Framework, `SaveChanges()` method already has transaction support.

In case of pure ADO.NET please see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/224702/210994

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADO transactions and send your transaction as a param to all your methods

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("connstringhere");
SqlTransaction transaction;
db.Open();
transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
try 
{
     INSERT(transaction);
     UPDATE(transaction);
     DELETE(transaction);
     INSERT(transaction);
     transaction.Commit();
} 
catch (SqlException sqlError) 
{
     transaction.Rollback();
}
```

Comment: sir I implemented your code but i do not know how to make my methods returnable. Could you please tell me what changes should be made in my all methods. i am using this :

public void INSERT()
{
//the code
}

Comment: @SandeepKumarThenua Hi. You can use SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery which return the number of affected rows, made by your query. So if it is -1, then throw SqlExecption. Another way is to catch @@error for your server, and handle it in your code. Or you could return the number of affected rows in your method:  public long INSERT()  { //the code; return SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); }, and make rollback if it is -1

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this topic: [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746.aspx).

> The TransactionScope class provides a simple way to mark a block of
>   code as participating in a transaction, without requiring you to
>   interact with the transaction itself. A transaction scope can select
>   and manage the ambient transaction automatically. Due to its ease of
>   use and efficiency, it is recommended that you use the
>   TransactionScope class when developing a transaction application. In
>   addition, **you do not need to enlist resources explicitly with the
>   transaction**. Any System.Transactions resource manager (such as SQL
>   Server 2005) can detect the existence of an ambient transaction
>   created by the scope and automatically enlist.

I would also like to recommend you to read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1690892/674700) and it's answers. It touches interesting topics about using transactions over multiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

Typically something like:

```
void DoStuff(args)
{
    using (var conn = CreateOpenConnection())
    using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // various operations here
            ForExample(conn, tran);
            tran.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            tran.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}

void ForExample(DbConnection conn, DbTransaction tran = null)
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.Transaction = tran;
        cmd.CommandText = "For example";
        // cmd.Parameters.Add(...)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Although most of this can be reduced using any of the tools / libraries that are available that sit above raw ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Net's TransactionScope class to achieve this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx
You can choose Isolation level's as per need. If you are not sure, please use the Serializable level which is the most consistent and least performant. But if your sql stored procedures have isolation levels, they will gain precedence. If this is a critical design please read about transactions before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create one stored procedure and based on a parameter execute your CRUD operations. For example:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF(@PartyID <= 0)
    BEGIN
        //INSERT
    IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RETURN
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        //UPDATE
    IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RETURN
        END
    END
```