# SET TRANSACTION error , C# , Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, transactions, commit, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have procedure in my C# device application app. This is how it looks:

```
private void stk_crane_start_movement()
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        OracleTransaction trans;
        trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Transaction = trans;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.AutoCommit = false;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "dc.stk_crane_start_movement";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_crane_opr_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = empid.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_crane_movement_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = pn_crane_movement_id_no.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pv_error", OracleDbType.VarChar));
        cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        string pv_error;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        pv_error = cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value.ToString();
        if (pv_error.ToString() == "")
        {
            trans.Commit();
            trans.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show("" + pv_error, "Error");
        }
    }
```

I'm getting `ORA-01453: SET TRANSACTION must be first statement of transaction` **at** `trans = conn.BeginTransaction();`

Can someone please explain to me what exactly i'm doing wrong?

I have also tried it like this:

```
private void stk_crane_start_movement()
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        OracleTransaction trans;
        trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        cmd.Transaction = trans;
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "dc.stk_crane_start_movement";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_crane_opr_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = empid.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_crane_movement_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = pn_crane_movement_id_no.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pv_error", OracleDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
        }

        catch
        {
            pv_error = cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("" + pv_error, "Error");

            try
            {
                trans.Rollback();
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Rollback failed" + ex, "Exception Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

But because its not an exception error that I'm expecting it doesn't go through the try catch statement.
I want it to rollback when my pv_error variable is populated. That is why I included a if statement in the first example.

Also I don't have any other transaction before this one..

Comment: what if you put conn.AutoCommit = false; before opening the transaction?

Comment: Try switching to use a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) instead. Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268430/how-to-implement-transaction/15268649#15268649)

Comment: Nope, still same error. tx tho

Answer (score 0):

There is a suggestion [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01453.php) that you may see this error if you already have an open transaction.  They advise committing or rolling back anything that's open.  Unlike in SQL Server, I have been able to issue prophylactic "COMMIT" statements in Oracle without even knowing whether I have anything open.

The only difference I see between your code and the [sample code here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracletransaction.aspx) is that they tie the command object to the connection before assigning the transaction to it:

```
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.Transaction = transaction;
```

You might want to try that variation.  You're not setting an isolation level, so the issue with [oracle oci.dll below version 10.2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/86e72cff-8c35-4994-8774-03535c06a744/) presumably doesn't apply here.

Comment: I have also seen your examples. I have edited my question. In there you will see I have tried it like the example you gave. I also explain why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry @Werner, I'm not sure what to try next. Did you try putting the "cmd.Transaction = trans;" before the BeginTransaction? Also, why not continue omitting the isolation level? Do you know the version number of your oci.dll? ... If you do find a solution, it would be great if you could post it for everyone's information.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracletransaction.aspx), your second version correctly uses the transaction. So if you combine that with your if statement, you should be fine:

```
  private void stk_crane_start_movement()
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        OracleTransaction trans;
        trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        cmd.Transaction = trans;
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "dc.stk_crane_start_movement";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_crane_opr_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = empid.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_crane_movement_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = pn_crane_movement_id_no.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pv_error", OracleDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            pv_error = cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value.ToString();                
            if (pv_error.ToString() == "")
            {
               trans.Commit();
               trans.Dispose();
               conn.Close();
               cmd.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
              trans.Rollback();
              MessageBox.Show("" + pv_error, "Error");
            }
```