# Can I first SELECT and then DELETE records in one t-SQL transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I can't figure out if this is an acceptable operation. I need to select records from the SQL Server 2008 database and then delete them, all as a single transaction from an ASP.NET code. Note that the .NET code must be able to retrieve the data that was first selected.

Something as such:

```
SELECT * FROM [tbl] WHERE [id] > 6;
DELETE FROM [tbl] WHERE [id] > 6
```

I'm [trying it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08da7/9) with the SQL Fiddle but then if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM [tbl]
```

I get the full table as if nothing was deleted.

**EDIT** As requested below here's the full .NET code to retrieve the records:

```
string strSQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM [tbl] WHERE [id] > 6;" +
    "DELETE FROM [tbl] WHERE [id] > 6";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLStatement, connectionString))
{
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
            //Read values
            val0 = rdr.GetInt32(0);
            val3 = rdr.GetInt32(3);
            //etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. But show us the code you're using please.

Comment: @PreetSangha: You mean .NET code? Or SQL? If you mean the latter, it's kind like what I showed above.

Comment: the .Net code is more important here

Comment: Why do you want it done in the same transaction?  There's no need to roll back a SELECT.  Is it that your application needs to know the set of records that are about to be deleted?

Comment: Your sqlfiddle works just fine. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08da7/11

Comment: @peterm: Oh. Maybe I just don't know how the SQLFiddle works :) Does it reset the table after I run my query?

Comment: The code **will be** something such as...? Does that mean you haven't actually tried it yet to know if it works or not? Premature optimization is trying to improve code you don't know needs improvement; is this a case of premature problem solving ("Can you solve the problem I don't have yet")?

Comment: @KenWhite: I was trying it out in Fiddle to see if it'd work before attempting to code it but then got the unexpected results from the Fiddle, and thus I'm asking here...

Comment: @c00000fd sqlfiddle resets the table schema only if you hit `Build Schema` or open a fiddle from a link (which automatically builds schema for you).

Comment: SQLFiddle is for MySQL. Your tags say SQL Server and T-SQL. :-) They're not the same. Test your queries in SQL Server Management Studio; you can create a temporary table to do so (`CREATE TABLE #test (...)`).

Comment: @peterm: So why does it show the full table if I run my query and then erase it and do `SELECT * FROM [tbl]`?

Comment: @KenWhite: No, I set it for SQL Server 2008. It's right on top. I also updated my C# code above to show what I mean to do.

Comment: Testing in SSMS would show you what the problem is here. The return value from multiple SQL statements is the result of the last statement run, which in this case is the `DELETE`. There are no rows returned from a `DELETE`, so there is nothing to read for `val0` and `val3`.

Comment: @KenWhite: OK. That's what I was afraid. Thanks. So how would you do this? As two execute statements? Or what user2246674 suggests below?

Comment: I posted a suggestion. I'm not sure which would work best for you, to be honest. You can probably test pretty easily to find out. :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will do the select and delete simultanious:

```
delete from [tbl] output deleted.* WHERE [id] > 6
```

Comment: Ooh, very nice and simple! I believe this approach avoids having to deal with explicit transactions entirely.

Comment: Hi, How do I get data that deleted ?

Comment: To capture output into a table variable, use the following:

delete from [tbl] output delete.* into @tableVar where [id] > 6

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to select and delete in the same transaction as long as both operations are enlisted in the same transaction.

Look at this post
[Transactions in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net)

Comment: Do you mean that I have to put `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and then `COMMIT` at the end?

Comment: Yes, but I would recommend that you manage the transactions through .Net and not the DB. That gives you better control from code

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "manage the transactions through .Net" please?

Comment: Check out the link I added

Answer (score 1):

The "easiest" way to achieve transactions with a compatible provider (SQL Server works great!) is to use a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). Just make sure the scope is created *before* the connection is opened so that everything is correctly enlisted.

The content of the `SelectStuff` and `DeleteStuff` methods doesn't matter much - just use the same connection, don't manually mess with the connection or with transactions, and perform the SQL operations however is best.

```cs
// Notes
// - Create scope OUTSIDE/BEFORE connection for automatic enlisting
// - Create only ONE connection inside to avoid DTC and "advanced behavior"
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
using (var conn = CreateConnection()) {
    // Make sure stuff selected is MATERIALIZED:
    // If a LAZY type (Enumerable/Queryable) is returned and used later it
    // may cause access to the connection outside of when it is valid!
    // Use "ToList" as required to force materialization of such sequences.
    var selectedStuff = SelectStuff(conn);

    DeleteStuff(conn);

    // Commit
    ts.Complete();

    // Know stuff is deleted here, and access selected stuff.
    return selectedStuff; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's an interesting approach. I didn't know that that class existed. I need to try it.

Comment: Also make sure you get the isolation of the transaction right.

Comment: @PreetSangha Good call - I normally default (as does TransactionScope) to serializable for update operations. Yeah, it's lazy and the correct isolation level is a whole different topic, but it'll either "work right" or "won't work".

Comment: Also make sure SelectStuff() is not deferred. It has to completely return the data before the scope completes.

Answer (score 0):

The return value from multiple SQL statements is the result of the last statement run, which in this case is the `DELETE`. There are no rows returned from a `DELETE`, so there is nothing to read for `val0` and `val3`.

There are two solutions I can think of here:

1. Change your code to expressly start a transaction, perform the `SELECT`, read the values, and then issue the `DELETE`, or
2. `SELECT` into a `#temp` table, execute the `DELETE`, and then `SELECT` from the `#temp` table, do what you need to with the rows, and then `DROP` th.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I was doing it as I showed it above is because I need this operation to be executed `atomically`.

Comment: There's no way to do it atomically, AFAIK, because the result of scripted statements is the result of the last statement executed. The second solution is probably the closest you're going to get, because it will remove the rows quickly (preventing other connections from reading them) and preserve them so you can still access them.