# TransactionScope v SQLTransaction

Tags: .net, vb.net, transactions

I have found the following quote: "It is recommended that you create implicit transactions using the TransactionScope class" on this website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx.  Has TransacrtionScope replaced the SQLTransaction class? i.e. should all new applications/transaction functionality use the TransactionScope class? If this is the case then I assume that SQLTransaction is just there so that legacy apps don't need changing?

I have read many webpages suggesting that TransactionScope should be used if multiple connections are used, but should TransactionScope be used if you have a signle connection that performs multiple operations that should be treated as an atomic unit of work?

Comment: Although there are a lot of duplicates to this question, you might find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net

Answer (score 1):

I personally like transactionScope because your queries to your database don't require a parameter for the sqlTransaction (or connection) or other related code to maintain the transaction. This typically allows your service/business layer to manage the transaction entirely which to me just reads cleaner.