# SQL INSERT for multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I can't figure out the wording to do a proper Google search.  I am writing a program in C# that writes to several tables at once(in sequence) in SQL Server.  The way I have it setup right now is I have different methods created that work on inserting for each table.  They all use the sql command/parameter structure.  And then when submit is clicked all of these methods are called and do there thing.  Should I be using a different way to insert into all the tables like store procedures?  My real main question - how do I fail all of the inserts if one fails.  Right now it has the unfortuate issue of continuing on and no way of undoing.

Comment: Put it into a transaction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net

Answer (score 3):

You should encapsulate your INSERTs into a transaction. The bad way to do it is to use a `TransactionScope` in ADO.NET, the good way is to write a stored procedure and `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK` your transaction inside you proc. You don't want to go back and forth form client to server while maintaing a transaction, because you will hurt concurreny and performance (exclusive locks are hold on the resources inserted until the transaction ends).

Here is a pseudo code example of T-SQL transaction management:

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT
    INSERT
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() -- you can use THROW in SQL Server 2012 to retrhrow the error
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for database transactions.
They can be either done in SQL or in C#.

Have a closer look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net) question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transactions look for IDbTransaction or TransactionScope for example.
in Stored Procs it would be easier to let the server decide if a rollback is needed or not.(FailureCode)
Yeah go with storedprocs it will be faster because of lesser overhead.
Transactions are possible either way