# How to handle transactions in .net objects?

Tags: c#, transactions

I am not talking about transactions at database level.  I woukld like to implement transactions at object level.  Here is my code:

```
WorkQueue wq = new WorkQueue();
wq.OWNER_ID = user.EmployeeId;
wq.OWNER_NM = user.FullName;
wq.WQ_DETAILS = txtDetails.Text;
wq.SOURCE_INFO = txtSource.Text;
wq.PRIORITY_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRequestType.SelectedItem.Value);
wq.PRO_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["pro_id"]);
wq.GROUP_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["cat_id"]);
wq.Save();

WQAttachment attachment = new WQAttachment();
attachment.ATTACH_SIZE = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength.ToString();
attachment.ATTACH_FILE = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
attachment.WQ_ID = wq.WQ_ID.Value;
attachment.ATTACH_FILE_NM = FileUpload1.FileName;
attachment.ATTACH_NM = "Upload test";
attachment.ATTACH_TYPE = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
attachment.Save();
```

Is there a way I can wrap this in a transaction so if attachment.save fails, it should roll back wq.save.  Thanks!

I see a SO answer regarding TransactionScope,  Can I use this for my case above?
[Transactions in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net?rq=1)

Comment: What is a `WorkQueue`? Does it handle transactions? If not, then the answer is "no"

Comment: It is simple POCO.  It doesn't handle transactions, but I can change the code to implement sql transactions within that class.

Comment: "Simple POCO" and "SQL" - I think you need to explain more. Clearly, it's persistent. Please ad some information about these classes to your question.

Comment: WorkQueue and WQAttachment are just two classes with some public properites and a public metod Save.  There is nothing special about them.  The Save method calls Enterprise Librarry methods to perform the save by calling a stored procedure.

Comment: I have little experience doing transactions, but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229975.aspx seems like a possible avenue to take.

Comment: If you are using Enterprise Library, then check to see if it has a way to handle transactions. The "Enterprise" suggests the answer is "yes". Otherwise, you can probably get away with using [`System.TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

Comment: @Aaron: no, he does not want to implement a resource manager. That's sort of the inverse of what he wants.

Comment: System.TransactionScope could be the solution to my problem here.  I will try an see if it works.  Thanks @JohnSaunders

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Oh, I must have mis-interpreted the question.  I thought the problem was that TransactionScope wouldn't work as is because the WorkQueue and WQAttachment don't support transactions.  I assumed TransactionScope would be used in the code above, and figured that link would show how to make whatever database interface you are using compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

System.TransactionScope works great for this scenario.  Thanks @Aaron and @JohnSaunders