# Update user and roles in single Db Call using MVC 5 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm new to Asp.net Identity. I'm trying to write a method which will update user details and its role. How can I achieve this by making single call to database.

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(DbContext);
 _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
```

Adding roles

```
_userManager.AddToRole(userId, role);
```

updating user

```
_userManager.Update(user);
```

Is there a way to call context.savechanges on usermanager so that I can make sure both action takes place or none?

Comment: You should use database transactions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27367675/2931427

Comment: It is also possible to instruct `UserManager` to not call `SaveChanges` automatically but that is a bit complex.