# ASP.NET MVC5/EF6 - AutoSaveChanges prematurely commiting Unit of Work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transactions, asp.net-identity, transactionscope

So I found this about prematurely commiting ([source](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/03/asp-net-identity-with-the-entity-framework.aspx)):

> One issue to be aware of is that the UserStore class does not play
>   well when using the unit of work design pattern. Specifically, the
>   UserStore invokes SaveChanges in nearly every method call by default,
>   which makes it easy to prematurely commit a unit of work. To change
>   this behavior, change the AutoSaveChanges flag on the UserStore.

So the problem is that changing that flag makes working with the Identity objects harder. For example, when creating a new user you don't get back its ID.

Also how would I save the changes in a class like AccountController in which by default you don't even have (or often need) to declare an ApplicationDbContext and you only have a UserManager and a SignInManager? I'd need to instantiate a new ApplicationDbContext and save that, which isn't a very good solution.

I found a solution that consisted of using database transactions, so something like this:

```cs
var dbContext = // get instance of your ApplicationDbContext
var userManager = // get instance of your ApplicationUserManager
using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
{
    try
    {
        var user = // crate your ApplicationUser
        var userCreateResult = await userManger.CreateAsync(user, password);
        if(!userCreateResult.Succeeded)
        {
            // list of errors in userCreateResult.Errors
            transaction.Rollback();
            return userCreateResult.Errors;
        }
        // new Guid for user now saved to user.Id property
        var userId = user.Id;

        var addToRoleresult = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "My Role Name");
        if(!addToRoleresult.Succeeded)
        {
            // deal with errors
            transaction.Rollback();
            return addToRoleresult.Errors;
        }

        // if we got here, everything worked fine, commit transaction
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        // log your exception
        throw;
    }
}
```

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27367675/3194577)

But I'm confused about how this really fixes anything. Lets say you have an execution order like this:

1. Add/Update something in the context, but don't save anything to the database
2. Execute UserManager.CreateAsync which would save the context (which we don't want yet)

If I surround this with a transaction, it would still happen the same way, except I could rollback it if I'd want to, right? But that doesn't really help, it only helps if something does go wrong, and I never want anything to wrong in the first place which is why I want control over when it saves. Maybe I'm just confused about how transactions work.

Comment: If you are using EF, why do you need Unit of Work? DbContext uses UoW internally, why do you need to re-implement it again?

Comment: Because that's what every single guide on the web is telling me to do. I realized this a few hours back when I found this MS article about the changes in EF6 and that I don't need to do this anymore. Of course, people stopped writting guides after EF6, because I've spent 2 days on this and there's only articles about what to do before EF6 and I only found out about what you said a couple of hours ago. Anyway, how would I unit test without UoW? With a custom UoW I could inject anything I'd want, but I don't know how I'd do that with just DbContext.

Comment: For unit testing I found the best approach is to send actual requests to a database using the real `DbContext`. Alternatively you can use repositories and provide mocks for them when you inject them, but I found this approach sub-optimal over time.

Comment: Those are integration tests though, right? Which is why I want to use repositories, but then I also read that since EF6 I don't need repositories either since I can just use DbSets?

Comment: Integration tests, yes. Repositories are good for updating, not for querying. Though I use less and less of them. Here is how we do integration tests: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/03/how-we-do-database-integration-tests-with-entity-framework-migrations/ this guide is a year old and almost nothing is changed in our approach.

Comment: I have to do unit tests though (this is a part of my university course)

Comment: Should've started from that then) In that case wrap `DbContext` into repositories and you can mock them for testing.

Comment: Can't I use DbSets instead of repositories though?

Comment: `DbSets` are also not very test-friendly. Though you might try `IDbSets` and mock them for tests, though I've not tried that route, so can't comment.

Comment: Can verify what @trailmax said. Repos with an injected and mocked dbcontext has worked the best for us in the past. No unit of work needed.

Comment: Alright, well the original question about prematurely committing still stands though