# SQLconnection does not support parallel transaction

Tags: c#

I have this code for inserting data into a database. Before I commit, I want to be sure that the data is entered successfully, then commit else rollback both inserts.

```
try {
    statement one commit;
    statement two commit;
}
catch {
    error message
    statement 1 Rollback();
    statement 2 Rollback();
}
finally {
    if (con.State == Con.Open)
        con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, and the title is confusing as 1) You're not creating a DB transaction in the psuedocode and 2) the statements aren't run in parallel.

Comment: Put all your insert script inside the try {} because they aren't parallel run if the try fails it will just go to the 'catch', you are essentially saying "try inserting this data but if it fails catch it".

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [Transactions in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

You were very near to do this, you just have to put one `commit` statement after the two statements, if the code reached to that point, this mean that the none of the any throw an exception, so you can do the commit because you are sure the two statements has been executed successfully.

```
try   
{
    statement one;
    statement two;
    commit;
}
catch  
{
     error message
     statement 1 Rollback();
     statement 2 Rollback();
}
finally
{
     if (con.State == Con.Open)
          con.Close();
}
```