# How to make a block of general code a transaction

Tags: c#

I have got the following code:

```
aClass.DoAJob();
bClass.DoAnotherJob();
cClass.DoAThirdJob();
```

I would like it to behave like a database transaction, ie. either all of them execute or none. Any suggestions?

NB This has nothing to do with multithreading or the like. It is just general code.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? What does each method do, for example?

Comment: Probably wants the operation to be atomic and roll back if it fails

Comment: @arynaq Yes, I understood that. Thanks.

Comment: @John like read some configs, update databases and then generate files.

Comment: you can use TransactionScope to achieve this; refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net

Comment: Suppose DoAJob does a Console.WriteLine, and then DoAThirdJob fails. How are you planning on un-ringing that bell? The user may have already read the console.

Comment: @AbhinawKaushik I thought that TransactionScope was for SQL commands? Am I mistaken?

Comment: It may be helpful for you to understand how databases achieve atomicity. Do you understand how a two-phase commit works?

Comment: @EricLippert I guess the console can just output something like 'output regenerated'. By understanding the 2PC, does that mean C# doesn't have such a general purpose transaction infrastructure and I have to create my own?

Comment: @AbhinawKaushik MSDN seems to only given examples on database transactions with `TransactionScope` even though that thread says it can be used for general purpose. I am not sure about it.

Comment: @Antediluvian _"does that mean C# doesn't have such a general purpose transaction infrastructure"_ The example given by Eric shows that such a general purpose transactional infrastructure wouldn't make much sense. So, yes: You want it, you code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general method for making a "transaction" is like this:

1. Preserve the old data in place
2. Write the new data to a temporary area
3. Perform an atomic operation to replace the old data with the new, e.g. by updating a pointer.

For in-memory operations, this is achieved trivially by using an object reference to point to state:

```
class Program
{

    static Point _position; //Points to latest position of something

    static void Move(int x, int y)
    {
        var temp = new Point(x, y);
        _position = temp;
    }
}
```

This example allows the program to move an object while guaranteeing that `x` and `y` are updated together.

For non-memory operations, the implementation of this pattern is specific to the medium. For example, for file operations, the program might write to a temporary file. When all operations are complete, the program would rename the file to the path expected by the user. This is probably how your browser's download feature works.

A similar mechanism exists for graphics (a frame buffer) and audio (audio buffer). And of course databases have their own particular mechanism that supports atomicity and concurrency, among other things.