# TransactionScope incorrectly commiting the transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, transactionscope

I have the following method in my DAL:

```
public void SavePlan()
{
    using (TransactionScope scope =
           new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        CallSaveDataProc();
        CallLogMsgProc();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

I have deliberately put a COMMIT Transaction in the `CallLogMsgProc` without creating a Transaction.  This results in a `SQLException` being thrown from `CallLogMsgProc` procedure and `scope.Complete()` never executes.

However, in my database, I'm still seeing records saved by the first method, `CallSaveDataProc`.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you put the code from CallSaveDataProc(), CallLogMsgProc() and any stored procedure you have used?

Answer (score 0):

Starting/committing transactions have to be paired, and preferably each pair should ideally be in the same scope (though each pair doesn't have to be in the same scope as another pair).

So you have a case of starting a transaction via the new `TransactionScope`, followed by `Commit` in your stored procedure ([which *will* save the work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187275)... as you are seeing), followed by an attempt to commit the transaction "seen" by `TransactionScope`, which has now become invalid.

Comment: So a commit in the child stored procedure would save the data even if the parent do end up rolling back?  I thought stored procedures in SQL always honoured the parent transaction.

Comment: @IftikharAli - SQL Server does not support nested transactions, so whatever you do, (e.g. commit/rollback) it will affect the single transaction.