# How to detect that rollback has occurred?

Tags: c#, sql-server, msdtc

I'm hunting down a bug in a large business application, where business processes are failing but partially persisted to the database. To make things harder to figure out, the process fails only once every few weeks, with hundreds of thousands successfully processed between every failure. The error frequency seems to go up when concurrency/number of worker processes goes up.

So far, we've been able to recreate what we're seeing with this program. (.NET 4.7.1 framework)

```cs
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Database1;Trusted_Connection=True"))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        // Doing some unwanted nested manual transaction and rolling it back
        var transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
        new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('This will be rolled back}')", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();

        transaction.Rollback();

        // Now doing some work with the DB.
        // You might expect it to become a part of transactionScope, but that is NOT the case!
        // So this command will actually succeed, with data written to the DB.
        new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('This will be inserted')", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Doing something which promotes the local transaction to a distributed transaction.
        using (var sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Database2;Trusted_Connection=True"))
        {
            // The program will fail here, with message "The transaction has aborted, Failure while attempting to promote transaction."
            sqlConnection2.Open();

            new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO TestTable2 VALUES('We will never come this far')", sqlConnection2).ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Our production code does not explicitly make calls to `transaction.Rollback()`, it is simply in my example as the means to reproduce the error message and behavior. But if any of our third party libraries makes this call, I would like to throw exception and exit as soon as possible. Preferably in the application layer.

How can I detect that the call to `Rollback()` has been made?  I really do not want to make crud operations without being sure that the `transactionScope` is able to do it's job.

#### Update 1

My unwanted "rollback" was caused by a bug somewhere in the connection sharing mechanism of .Net. The bug is reproduced on all .Net Framework version between 4.5.1 and 4.8, and also on the new [System.Data.SqlClient package](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient).

An [issue has been added to the System.Data.SqlClient repository](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/237).

Comment: The `Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status` property is `Active` right until the program fails.

Comment: maybe you have a deadlock in sql server you can monitor the dead lock and transaction of sql server with extended event and resource monitor in os or many good tools like apex sql monitor

Comment: sql server tracks transactions and rollbacks etc.... you can query what it did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different transaction APIs don't all work together.  So you're in dangerous territory here.

> How can I detect that the call to Rollback() has been made?

`select @@trancount` should always tell you.  The rollback will revert @@trancount to 0.

Comment: Logging `@@trancount` helped me find the root cause. When inconsistencies occur, `@@trancount` is `0` immediately after `using (var transaction = new TransactionScope() {`. So no rollback has been made, but something else is wrong here.

Comment: My problems were actually caused by a bug in somewhere in connection sharing mechanism of .Net. https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/237