# Transaction Stored Procedure C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, transactions

I am having a slight issue. Please guide me.
I am coding in C#(Console App). I have called 2 different stored procedure in my code. Basically both these stored procedures access the same table.
First SP has a select query and an update query.
Second SP has a single update query.

Now I want to call these SP in a transaction mode(Either all succeeds or is second SP fails rollback first SP). I have used "TransactionScope" within my C# code but is doesnt seem to work fine. ie when I stop the Console App sometimes I see that the first SP is executed and the second one fails.

Can anybody suggest me on this.

Regards,
Justin Samuel.

Comment: How are you using the transaction scope in your code (with using statement or try/catch)?

Comment: Yes Goran, I using "using" statement like:
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())

enclosed in a try/catch block.

and the calls to the SPs are within this scope

Comment: I don't see how this goes wrong. How about adding a rollback call in your OnExit method? This should ensure rollback is called when you stop the console app and transaction isn't completed.

Comment: Does anybody have idea of what could be the issue?
The scenario is like, when I open the third instance of the Console App it times out.I am getting the following exception:

SqlException - "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Could this because of SP taking more time. The SP simply has a select of the Top ID and updates a column of this Top ID. I think I need not change the CommandTimeout as the SP is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `TransactionScope`, it **should** work fine, but the scope *must* surround the **connection(s)**:

```
using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope()) {
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs)) {
      // either multiple commands on one connection
      using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        // etc
      }
      using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        // etc
      }
    }
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs)) {
      // or a separate connection
      using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        // etc
      }
    }
    tran.Complete();
}
```

There *is* [an edge case where a `TransactionScope` can fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189534/net-transactionscope-class-and-t-sql-tran-commit-and-rollback#190332) causing the later command to run without a transaction.

Alternatively, for a single connection use `SqlTransaction`, but remember to associate the transaction (from the connection) to each command.

Comment: Marc,
I am bit confused. I am fetching one row at a time. Doin some processing using the two SPs. This individual row processing is in a TransactionScope. If I write SqlConnection within each Transaction it would mean separate connection in each transaction.

Please suggest if I am wrong!

Comment: Finally, I had to create a separate connection within each transaction.
Excellent Marc!!!
Thanks Marc and Goran for the support.
Cheers!!!

Comment: Sounds like you are blocking yourself due to serializable isolation level.

Comment: Marc, I working perfectly fine with two instance of Console opened. and the transaction works just smoothly.
However when I open a third Console App, i just timesOut. Need to investigate this! :)