# update multiple table using one query in SQL SERVER

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, database

I am working on asp.net(c#) project with SQL SERVER 2008. I want to update three tables using one query. Please suggest me how to do that. thnaks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't**. Update statement works for a single table. You have to write three different queries for three tables.

You can use transaction to make sure that your update statements are atomic.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE Table1
Set Field1 = '1';
Where Field = 'value';

UPDATE Table2
Set Field1= '2'
Where Field = 'value';

UPDATE Table3
Set Field1= '3'
Where Field = 'value';

COMMIT
```

For C# you can use [SqlTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx). An example from the same link (bit modified)

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;

        // Start a local transaction.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

        // Must assign both transaction object and connection 
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "UPDATE Table1 Set Field1 = '1' Where Field = 'value';";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText =
                "UPDATE Table2 Set Field1= '2' Where Field = 'value'";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.CommandText =
                "UPDATE Table3 Set Field1= '3' Where Field = 'value'";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

            // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
                // a closed connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write three queries and put them all into a single transaction, either in a stored procedure or using `TransactionScope` from your c# code.

```
using System.Transactions;

using( var ts = new TransactionScope() ){

  // execute your queries

  ts.Complete();
}
```

Full example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One of the way will be create a procedure and inside that procedure update  all the table. You can also use transaction if you want to insert all the three or non of them. Here is an [example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/02/sql-server-stored-procedure-and-transactions/)

You can also maintain transaction from C#. here is an example
[Transaction Stored Procedure C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825833/transaction-stored-procedure-c-sharp)

Example

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your connectionstring"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
    try
    {
        using (var command1 = new SqlCommand("SP1Name", connection, transaction))
        {
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 "The best way" is an antipattern. This is totally unneeded for this - and a maintenance issue, to do that for every possible combination. THis is what transactions were created for.